# Sqlalchemy session.rollback from IntegrityError causes queuepool to run out of handlers?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have the following table:

```
class Feedback(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'feedbacks'
  __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'look_id'),)
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
  look_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('looks.id'), nullable=False)
```

I am currently inserting a lot of entries into this table that will be violating that UniqueConstraint.

I am using the following code:

```
  for comment in session.query(Comment).filter(Comment.type == Comment.TYPE_LOOK).yield_per(100):
    feedback = Feedback()
    feedback.user_id = User.get_or_create(comment.model_id).id
    feedback.look_id = comment.commentable_id
    session.add(feedback)
    try:        # Refer to T20
      session.flush()
    except IntegrityError,e:
      print "IntegrityError", e
      session.rollback()
  session.commit()
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
IntegrityError (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "feedbacks_user_id_look_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, look_id)=(140, 263008) already exists.
 'INSERT INTO feedbacks (user_id, look_id, score) VALUES (%(user_id)s, %(look_id)s, %(score)s) RETURNING feedbacks.id' {'user_id': 140, 'score': 1, 'look_id': 263008}
IntegrityError (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "feedbacks_user_id_look_id_key"
...
(there's about 24 of these integrity errors here)
...
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, look_id)=(173, 263008) already exists.
 'INSERT INTO feedbacks (user_id, look_id, score) VALUES (%(user_id)s, %(look_id)s, %(score)s) RETURNING feedbacks.id' {'user_id': 173, 'score': 1, 'look_id': 263008}
No handlers could be found for logger "sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load.py", line 40, in <module>
    load_crawl_data_into_feedback()
  File "load.py", line 21, in load_crawl_data_into_feedback
    for comment in session.query(Comment).filter(Comment.type == Comment.TYPE_LOOK).yield_per(100):
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2337, in instances
    fetch = cursor.fetchmany(self._yield_per)
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3230, in fetchmany
    self.cursor, self.context)
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3223, in fetchmany
    l = self.process_rows(self._fetchmany_impl(size))
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3343, in _fetchmany_impl
    row = self._fetchone_impl()
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3333, in _fetchone_impl
    self.__buffer_rows()
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3326, in __buffer_rows
    self.__rowbuffer = collections.deque(self.cursor.fetchmany(size))
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) named cursor isn't valid anymore None None
```

Before you jump to conclusions about this error being caused by yield_per, I can assure you that yield_per is not the culprit here.

I tried the same code without the unique constraints and I did not experience any error at all.

I believe that the integrity errors are causing **No handlers could be found for logger "sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool"**.

I assume that every integrity error is killing each "thread" in the queuepool.

Can someone enlighten me as to what is happening?

If I can't do much about the data at this point, what would you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is just from the Python `logging` module; your pool class is trying to log some debug message but you don't have SQLA logging configured.  [Configuring logging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#configuring-logging) is easy, and then you can see what it's actually trying to say.

I'm not *quite* sure what's going on here, but it certainly doesn't help that you're rolling back your top-level transaction dozens of times.  Rollback ends the transaction and invalidates every live row object.  That certainly won't interact well with `yield_per`.

If your database supports savepoints or nesting transactions (i.e., is Postgres or Oracle...  or *maybe* recent MySQL?), try starting a nested transaction for each attempt:

```
for comment in session.query(Comment).filter(Comment.type == Comment.TYPE_LOOK).yield_per(100):
    try:
        with session.begin_nested():
            feedback = Feedback()
            feedback.user_id = User.get_or_create(comment.model_id).id
            feedback.look_id = comment.commentable_id
            session.add(feedback)
            session.flush()
    except IntegrityError, e:
        print "IntegrityError", e

session.commit()
```

`with` rolls back on error and commits on success, so a failed `flush` won't wreak havoc on the rest of your main transaction.

If you don't have the backend support, the other sensible options coming to mind are:

- Complexify your query: do a `LEFT JOIN` with your feedback table so you know in-app whether or not the feedback row already exists.
- If you're willing to make `(user_id, look_id)` be your primary key, I think you can use [`session.merge(feedback)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#unitofwork-merging).  This acts like an insert-or-update based on primary key: if SQLA can find an existing row with the same pk, it'll update that, else it'll create a new one in the database.  Would risk firing off an extra `SELECT` for every new row, though.

Answer (score 4):

"Before you jump to conclusions about this error being caused by yield_per, I can assure you that yield_per is not the culprit here. "

I'm not sure why you'd think that - yield_per() is very important here, and this could be divined quickly by simply trying out the same test *without* the yield_per() to see if the behavior is different.   By using yield_per(), a psycopg2 cursor is being kept open as that loop continues.  But then you're emitting a ROLLBACK on the psycopg2 connection via `session.rollback()`.  That would exactly cause an error like "named cursor isn't valid anymore " to occur.   In fact the only reason there *is* a named cursor is because that's how you do server side cursors with psycopg2 which is part of what yield_per() enables.

"I tried the same code without the unique constraints and I did not experience any error at all."

this is because without constraints, no exception is thrown, and the rollback() isn't hit.